# Bruce Eckel ThinkingIn Java 4-th edition, ThreadLocalVariableHolder

Tags: java, multithreading

Two snippets from book (Concurrency chapter):

```
 class Accessor implements Runnable {
    private final int id;

    public Accessor(int idn) {
      id = idn;
    }

    public void run() {
      while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
        ThreadLocalVariableHolder.increment();
      System.out.println(this);
      Thread.yield();
      }
   }

   public String toString() {
   return "#" + id + ": " +
     ThreadLocalVariableHolder.get();
   }
}

public class ThreadLocalVariableHolder {

private static ThreadLocal<Integer> value =
  new ThreadLocal<Integer>(); /*{
  private Random rand = new Random(47);
  protected synchronized Integer initialValue() {
    return rand.nextInt(10000);
  }
};*/

public static void increment() {
  value.set(value.get() + 1);
}

public static int get() {
  return value.get();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  ExecutorService exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

  for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    exec.execute(new Accessor(i));

  TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3); // Run for a while
  exec.shutdownNow();
  // All Accessors will quit
}
}
```

In class *ThreadLocalVariableHolder* is inner class *ThreadLocal* with method *initialValue* and attribute *rand*, wich are not explicitly used. If I comment whole content of class (as I did here), it still generates similar results. I suppose, that this code is obsolete. Do you anybody understand, why is this code inside the inner class and what is the purpose?

Comment: Solved, example works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt, if I run your code it throw NPE at `increment() -> value.get()`

Which is valid because the default implementation in `ThreadLocal` will return `null`

```
protected T initialValue() {
        return null;
    }
```

From `JavaDoc`

> Returns the current thread's "initial value" for this thread-local variable. This method will be invoked the first time a thread accesses the variable with the get method, unless the thread previously invoked the set method, in which case the initialValue method will not be invoked for the thread. Normally, this method is invoked at most once per thread, but it may be invoked again in case of subsequent invocations of remove followed by get.
>
> **This implementation simply returns null**; if the programmer desires thread-local variables to have an initial value other than null, ThreadLocal must be subclassed, and this method overridden. Typically, an anonymous inner class will be used.

Comment: Yes, I copy completelly the same code into a new simple project. Than it issues NullPointerException as expected. The problem will be not in example, but in another point. Solved.

Answer (score 0):

Because behavior of this sample was strength, I don't delete this mistaken code. To reproduce it. Uncomment commented lines in inner Class, compile it, than comment back and try it. I had to go to the build section and delete the .class files to obtain NullPointerException. Reproducible on NetBeans 8.0, JDK 1.7. May be it is reported as a bug bind somehow with inner classes.

For explanation of this example. ThreadLocal class is prepared class in java.lang and it has special features [ThreadLocal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html), which are not so common:

> This class provides thread-local variables. These variables differ
>   from their normal counterparts in that each thread that accesses one
>   (via its get or set method) has its own, independently initialized
>   copy of the variable. ThreadLocal instances are typically private
>   static fields in classes that wish to associate state with a thread
>   (e.g., a user ID or Transaction ID).

I must say, that was easier to write its own class, than understand what is doing that ThreadLocal class even if or just because original solution is more concise.